# Как считать xml-файл в String, оставляя пробелы,но удаляя переносы строк?

Tags: java, xml

Как считать xml-файл полностью в String, оставляя пробелы,но удаляя переносы строк?

Answer (score 1):

Считать откуда и чем? Если просто каким-нибудь reader'ом, то можно читать построчно и сохранять в один `StringBuilder`

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToYourXML"))) {
    String line;
    StringBuilder XMLInString = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        XMLInString.append(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: вы аппендите билдер в сам себя?)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov исправил, спасибо

Comment: он не будет удалять пробелы? У меня есть реализация 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(bodyPath));
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            convertXmlToString += in.next();
        }
        in.close(); 
и она удаляет

Comment: Нет, ничего внутри строк не удаляется. Или вы имеете ввиду пробелы между строками?

Comment: пробелы между словами, мне нужно SOAP запрос отправить и чтобы никаких пробелов не удалялось между словами) Получится?

Comment: Да, ничего не должно удаляться

Comment: спасибо большое! )

А можно усложнить задачу, и считывать файл именно так, как он есть, вместе с переносами строк?

Comment: @Ivan Считывать нет, однако переносы строк можно добавить таким образом:
`XMLInString.append(line).append("\n");`